# #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (macOS vs code solution)

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code

I recently used migration assistant to switch between macs and I'm shown the error below:

[image]

Also, if I use any other header file other than `#include <iostream>` the code works fine. Also, if I run the code while I'm having this error, the code works and I'm unable to understand what is happening.

I tried to search the solution but all the online solutions are for windows and not for macOS. I'm new to the macOS system so I'm having a hard time understanding how to fix this. If anyone can help, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac)?

Comment: Developer: Reload Window in VSCode settings worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade your OS recently coz mine brought the same error after upgrading to Monterey.
If so, run this command in your terminal to download & install command line tools package.

`xcode-select --install`

See [similar thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a).